# interaction between audio stream and ios audio player

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming

Here is a thing.
There is a small site with a play/pause button that plays a live audio stream.

`rstlss.live`

So, when you open it on phone and press play or pause - everything works fine. But if you leave audio playing, lock the screen, press power button on phone (any button that wakes up your phone without unlocking) then press pause in phone's mini-player - audio will pause. But then you unlock the phone, proceed to page in the browser - and button didn't change its state. You will have to press pause first and then play to restart playback.

Is there any option to connect these two things?
Here is the full code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>rstlss//live</title>
 <style>
    body{ background:#666; }
    button#playpausebtn{
    background:url(assets/images/pause.png);
    border:none;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    cursor:pointer;
</style>

    <script>
    var audio, playbtn, seek_bar;
function initAudioPlayer(){
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "http://78.155.172.94:8000/download.mp3";
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play();
    playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
    playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause);
    function playPause(){ 
        if(audio.paused){
            audio.play();
            playbtn.style.background = "url(assets/images/pause.png) no-repeat";
        } else {
            audio.pause();
            playbtn.style.background = "url(assets/images/play.png) no-repeat";
        }
    }

}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="playpausebtn"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

It is expected that when you press pause in ios audio player in locked mode the play/pause button in browser also will change it state according to player.